# Connecting to WPA2-Enterprise using Powershell?

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, wifi-configuration, wpa2

I'm writing a script to automatically install Software after system setup. But for that to work I need to have it auto-connect to a WPA2-Enterprise wifi network without user interaction. How can I do that with powershell?

Comment: If it can be done, more details are needed. What type of authentication is being used on the wifi network? Are you talking about running this script from a system context, or a user context? Will it be running pre-login or post-login?

Comment: Try: netsh wlan connect name="SSID"

Comment: It's PEAP. Since this is for an unattended system install, it's crucial that I can provide the credentials via that API. I've found that new "Windows.Devices.WiFi" namespace, but that doesn't look very convincing either...

Comment: Ok, apparently somewhere out there, a "netcmd.exe" from Microsoft is floating around. On the Windows IoT Core ISO. But I don't have that...